# Polynomial functions.

Tags: polynomials

A friend of mind needs help with this exercise.
A step by step walkthrough is highly appreciated.

He's francophone that's why the text is written in french. 
I'll try and translate the pieces of text as best as I can.

So, let a, b and c be three real numbers that verify the following condition:

$a+bx+cx^2 > 0$ for every $x≥1$ .

We consider the function:

...

Where ln designates a natural logarithm.

We suppose that:

...

We deduce that the coefficient is:

...

Which -if any- of the 5 is correct ?

[image: This is what he sent me]

Answer (score 3):

The values of $1/f(2)$, $1/f(3)$ and $1/f(4)$ each give you a linear equation in the unknowns $a,b,c$.  Solve...

Chacune des valeurs de $1/f(2)$, $1/f(3)$ et $1/f(4)$ vous donne une équation linéaire en les inconnues $a,b,c$.  Résoudre...

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you have the system
$$a+2b+4c=8\\a+3b+9c=15\\a+4b+16c=24$$ from which (*you have several ways to find the value of $b$*) you can get the correct answer is given by C).